# SQLite Cordova (Ionic) does not work on phone or another computer, but works on bluestacks

Tags: android, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework

When I run the ionic app I'm working on, if I run it on the computer using bluestacks, it Works, but when I try to do it on my phone, it does not work. Also, on a colleague's computer, it does not work either.

The error code is "Application Error

The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (http://192.168.201.55:8100)"

Followed often by "Application Error
net::ERR_CONNETION_TIMED_OUT (same IP as above)"

Needless to say that I'm not trying to employ an online DB, but an offline one. Here is the relevant part of my code, I will include any relevant information in order to find out how to fix my code if you think you need more info.

```
private database: SQLiteObject;
private dbReady = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

constructor(private platform:Platform, private sqlite:SQLite) {
 this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'todos.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
    .then((db:SQLiteObject)=>{
      this.database = db;

      this.createTables().then(()=>{     
        //communicate we are ready!
        this.dbReady.next(true);
      });
    })

  });
}
```

Comment: What is on the server http://192.168.201.55:8100?

Comment: Thats my local pc (where emulator is) adress, but I do not know what is going on at port 8100. Is there any way that I could find out? I believe the DB is somehow believed to be on my pc and that the phone is trying to reach it.

Comment: Have you checked if this ip is present in index.html?

Comment: index.html does not have any IP on any part of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the ip to index.html (this could be a CSP issue):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* 
http://192.168.201.55:8100
... other ip addresses ...
data: gap:;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
media-src *;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
```

See https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/

and https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: It works, however, ¿is it an external resource? Because I am trying to make a local DB that is meant to work without net connection.

Comment: It seems, that sqlite connecting to db using ip address which is identified by it. You may see CSP issues in Chrome console using chrome://inspect (USB debugging should be enabled on the phone).